# LUA count repeating characters in string

Tags: string, lua, count, symbols

I have a string "A001BBD0" and i want to know this info:

- 0 repeats 3 times
- B repeats 2 times

and that's it.

I found this pattern on web: "([a-zA-Z]).*(\1)" but it always returns nil for some reason

I guess i should split this string and check each symbol in several loops. I don't think this is a good idea (low performance)

i also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608299/lua-pattern-matching-repeating-character) topic but it doesn't give me any information

Comment: BTW, it's Lua, not LUA.

Comment: sorry) i didn't know that this is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a record for each alphanumeric char will give a more generic solution

```
local records = {} -- {['char'] = #number of occurances}
s = "A001BBD0"
for c in string.gmatch(s, "%w") do
    if records[c] then
        records[c] = records[c] + 1
    else
        records[c] = 1
    end
end

for k,v in pairs(records) do
    if(v > 1) then -- print repeated chars
        print(k,v)
    end
end
-- Output:
-- 0    3
-- B    2
```

Comment: thanks you, it works. But now i have another problem. I use russian letters too as a pattern [АВЕКМНОРСТУХ] but it counts twice for some reason. I can't understand why

Comment: which Russian letters are you being counted twice?

Comment: А (this letter looks like english A but it's not) When i print russian word (after all functions) i keep getting empty strings (idk why). I tried to use string.byte/string.char to avoid this problem - same result. I guess Lua doesn't support other languages

Comment: I think i should replace russian letters with english ones and it'll fix everything

Comment: If you want to count Russian letters (and not other characters, such as spaces), you may have to install a library such as [luautf8](https://github.com/starwing/luautf8), which contains versions of the Lua string-matching functions in which Cyrillic is matched by the character class `"%w"`. Or you can count all UTF-8 characters by replacing `"%w"` with `utf8.charpattern` in the loop in this post (assuming you are using Lua version 5.3), and then you will have information on the Cyrillic characters.

Comment: Replace `string.gmatch(s, "%w")` with `string.gmatch(s, "[^%s%c%p\128-\191][\128-\191]*")` to handle Russian letters.

Answer (score 9):

`gsub` returns the number of substitutions. So, try this code:

```
function repeats(s,c)
    local _,n = s:gsub(c,"")
    return n
end

print(repeats("A001BBD0","0"))
print(repeats("A001BBD0","B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version of the previous answer about use of the ternary operator

```
local records = {}
s = "A001BBD0"
for c in string.gmatch(s, "%w") do
    records[c] = records[c] and records[c] + 1 or 1
end

for k,v in pairs(records) do
    if(v > 1) then -- print repeated chars
        print(k,v)
    end
end
```

Comment: records[c] = (records[c] or 0) + 1

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even shorter answer than the previous ones that I just came up with.

This is the simplest, and most efficient way to count repeating characters in a string on Lua.

```
local str = "A001BBD0"

local count_0 = #string.gsub(str, "[^0]", "") -- count the 0's only
local count_B_and_0 = #string.gsub(str, "[^B0]", "") -- count the B's and 0's together

print(count_0, count_B_and_0)
```