# Lua-filters in Pandoc: replacing string with text from file

Tags: string, replace, lua, include, pandoc

Fair warning, I'm rather inexperienced with programming in general.

When generating outputs from markdown documents, my goal is to replace placeholders (e.g. '{{string}}') with text from an external file with the same name (i.e. 'string.md'). I've been able to achieve replacing the string with the first line of text of an .md file.

However, I'm struggling to find a way to replace a string with multiple lines of text (essentially an include function).

The code for the first task was based on some examples from the [Pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#examples):

```
function file_exists(file)
  local f = io.open(file, "rb")
  if f then f:close() end
  return f ~= nil
end

function lines_from(file)
  if not file_exists(file) then return {} end
  lines = {}
  for line in io.lines(file) do 
    lines[#lines + 1] = line
  end
  return lines
end

return {
  {
    Str = function (elem)
      if elem.text:match ("{{.+}}") then
        file_name = elem.text:match ("{{.+}}")
        file_name = file_name:gsub("{{","")
        file_name = file_name:gsub("}}","")
        local file = 'lua-filters/'..file_name..'.md'
            if not file_exists(file) then
            return elem
            else
            local lines = lines_from(file)
            return pandoc.Str(elem.text:gsub("{{.+}}",lines[1]))
        end
      else
        return elem
      end
    end,
  }
}
```

Every time a place holder '{{string}}' is found, it will be replaced with the first line of the corresponding file 'string.md'. An example:

```
{{project}} is the project name.

The project number is {{projectno}}.
```

turns into:

```
Project Name is the project name.

The project number is 456321.
```

With a second lua-filter, I want to be able to use a place holder string, where - instead of only the first line - the full content of the text file is returned. However, I've been unable to *either* find a way to return all lines of the corresponding file (using the same code as above) *or* convert the content of the file in a more appropriate element.

The desired outcome would be:

```
## Include section

}}lorem-ipsum{{
```

Turns into:

```
## Include section

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....

Ut enim ad minim veniam...
```

With "Lorem ipsum..." being the context of the file 'lorem-ipsum.md'. Using `pairs` I was only able to return the first line:

```
        if not file_exists(file) then
        return elem
        else
        local lines = lines_from(file)
        for k,v in pairs(lines) do
        return pandoc.Str(v)
        end
```

Another approach might be to use `Para` and `elem.content[1].text` instead of `Str` and `elem.text`, but I've been unable to figure out if/how the file should be handled differently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps gsub is not being asked to preform the search replace for ALL entries, just for the first? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608299/lua-pattern-matching-repeating-character

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The search and replace (from the first snippet of code) actually works as intended. The issue I'm having, is that I'm unable to replace a string with multiple lines of text. I'll edit the post to clarify.

Comment: There is a new [include-files lua-filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/include-files). The included files should be inside pandoc code blocks.